# Installing Optifine on Minecraft 1.12.1 without installing Java on macOS

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos, minecraft-optifine

So I installed Minecraft on my macOS computer. I want to install Optifine as well. When I download Optifine Ultra from its website, I get a `.jar` file. When I double click on it, I get the following message:

> To use the “`java -jar OptiFine_1.12.2_HD_U_C7.jar” command-line tool you need to install a JDK.

Along with this, I get an option to go to the Oracle website to download the 300+MB Java Development Kit.

Is it possible to 'manually' install Optifine without having to install the JDK?

Comment: It really says "JDK", not "JRE"? Weird. Does it work with Forge?

Comment: Yes, perhaps this is for Mac only? I haven't tried Forge yet. I'm just trying to keep everything I install to a minimum

Comment: I would appreciate it if my down voter explained to me why I was down voted!

Comment: Forge can load Optifine just like any other mod, that's why I'm asking. You can then just rename the profile to "optifine" and have the same effect as with just Optifine installed.

Comment: Possible reason for downvotes: This could be interpreted as tech support for modded Minecraft, which is off-topic here. However, I don't see it as that, that's why I'm still trying to help.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It seems like I need to do the same exact thing to install Forge though.

Comment: Then it might actually be a requirement to run it.

Comment: This seems to be technical support for *modding* (instead of *modded*) Minecraft, as Fabian could be referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be possible to use Minecraft's bundled instance of Java by navigating to the runtime folder used by the game, but that may not work, or even be the correct release (JDK) and version (8) needed to run the installer.  I'd recommend just installing the JDK as there isn't really any reason to not have it, and some things may break without it during the install process.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to install OptiFine manually, you'll need to access the json file from the versions folder, so you'll need to install it either way. If you have a different computer that does have java, install it on that, then go to your versions folder, optifine 1.12.2, and copy the .json file to the same directory on your other computer. That directory won't exist, so you'll need to create it, but it should work fine.